# How to change cell dimensions with ComplexHeatmap?

Tags: r, heatmap

I'm attempting to create a heatmap in R using ComplexHeatmap. I used the below section of code to create a heatmap:

```
Heatmap(gsea.heatmap.df,
         cluster_rows = FALSE,
         cluster_columns = FALSE,
         show_row_dend = FALSE,
         show_column_dend = FALSE,
         col = colorRamp2(c(-1, 0, 1), c("red", "white", "blue")),
         heatmap_legend_param = list(color_bar = "continuous",
                                     at = c(0, -0.1, -0.2, -0.3, -0.4, -0.5, -0.6, -0.7, -0.8, -0.9, -1),
                                     labels = c("1", "0.9", "0.8", "0.7", "0.6", "0.5", "0.4", "0.3", "0.2", "0.1", "0")))
```

The resultant heatmap can be seen below:

[image: ComplexHeatmap heatmap]

However, the dimensions of each cell of the heatmap are stretched out. I've attempted to find which parameter is used to control the dimensions of each cell, but I can't find it. Ideally I'd like to make each cell a perfect square. Is there a way for me to easily alter the dimensions of cells in a heatmap?

Answer (score 0):

It defaults to fit the width allowed for the image, which can change as you resize. I don't believe the developers of ComplexHeatmap have given users control of the per cell width. You can monkey around with the `width` parameter, which controls the width of a single heatmap, to see if that helps. But I suspect it's going to vary when you resize the plot.

Answer (score 0):

Just to complete De Novo's answer,

> It defaults to fit the width allowed for the image, which can change as you resize.

This is the suggestion given in ComplexHeatmap's [documentation](https://jokergoo.github.io/ComplexHeatmap-reference/book/other-tricks.html#set-the-same-cell-size-for-different-heatmaps-with-different-dimensions):

> In the heatmap generated by ComplexHeatmap, all the heatmap components have absolute size and only the size of the heatmap body (or the size of the cells) is changable (or in other words, if you change the size of the final graphic device, e.g. by draging the graphics window if you plot in, only the size of the heatmap body is adjusted), which means, the size of the whole plot is linearly related to the number of rows or columns in the heatmap. This implies we can actually fit a linear model `y = a*x + b` where e.g. `y` is the height of the whole plot and `x` is the number of rows.